# jQueryUI sortable, show a helper tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have two divs, each contain sortable elements but once I start dragging it should only show a basic tooltip instead of the complete sortable element(orginal element should stay visible upon it gets dropped into the new list).

I cant seem to find a example on the web, any help would be nice!

Comment: Please post example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`helper`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) option to set a custom element to display.

> Allows for a helper element to be used for dragging display. Multiple
>   types supported:
>
> - String: If set to "clone", then the element will be cloned and the clone will be dragged.
> - Function: A function that will return a DOMElement to use while dragging.

Side note: when you start sorting, the element is set to hidden. By attaching a handler to the start event I re-show it..

Code:

```
$("#sortable_nav").sortable({
    helper: function () {
        return $("<div class='custom'>I'm a custom tooltip</div>");
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).show();
    }
});
```

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RpZ7G/